# Bilinear Coons patches

Tags: differential-geometry, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that we have two bilinear Coons patches which share a common curve. Studying on Farin I find that, generally, these two surfaces join with C^0 continuity along that common curve, but I don't know why. Thanks.

Comment: What's a Coon's patch, a blackberry patch for raccoons?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coons_patch

Comment: It's "Coons patch", not "Coon's patch". There is no coon involved. Named after Steven Coons, one of the founding fathers of computer graphics and computer-aided design. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Coons

Answer (score 1):

Look at the equation for a Coons patch, $P(s,t)$. If you set $s=0$, or $s=1$ or $t=0$ or $t=1$, the equation degenerates into one of the defining curve equations. In other words, the patch exactly interpolates all four of its defining curves.

So, if two patches share a common curve, each of them has an edge that exactly matches this curve. Those two edges therefore match each other (in position) which means that the two patches meet with $C_0$ continuity.

To show that two patches do not join in a $C_1$ fashion, in general, all you need is a counterexample -- a simple example of two patches that share a common edge but are not $C_1$. A trivially simple example will work. Define each patch by four line segments that form a square. Then the patch will simply be the planar region in the interior of the square. If the two squares are not coplanar, then the join will not be $C_1$.

Another approach is to calculate partial derivatives, and show that they are not equal, in general, but that seems more difficult, to me.

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake formulating the question. Why the continuity is ONLY C^0? Do I have to work with partial derivatives to proove that the two patches are non C^1 along that curve? Thanks.

Comment: see edits to answer